# How could I create a system for my trading bots

Tags: python, class, object, oop, architecture

I want to create  a system where I can manage a privet trading bots ,I don't Know how to architects it
with OOP or create a file for each bot
I will store the strategies in one file so I can import it
create  a class for the bot that have stop and start methods

this is all easy , what I don't Know to do is how to create many bots Objects from this class and manage their statues STOPPES or ACTIVE
I will manage it through GUI(start or stop it) , and show some info from database
the only problem is how I will manage the objects , like I'm a user(object)that do a functions and has info how
does I create an object -- store its info in DB --- start method activated --- ? then what I don't understand

how would you plan this system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write bots in a separate projects and run them via a ***subprocess*** from main file. Just create main.py with GUI and set functions that calls or stops your bots.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'bot1.py'])  # on start button
p.kill()  # on stop button
```

Also you can track subprocess activity using Python. See [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for other details.